# Using categories tag pair with related categories mode

Tags: categories

I'm having issues trying to display a category name when using the related categories option. Two snippets below:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="4" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes"}
```

And inside of the above:

```
{categories limit="1" show="not 1"}{category_name}{/categories}
```

When I remove `related_categories_mode` the categories will display fine, but it's unfortunately necessary for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes `{categories}` loop not working with `related_categories_mode`.

you can work around this problem using `{embed}` template and pass the entry_id to it then call `{categories}` loop.

or you can use addons Like gwcode_categories  http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/examples/example1

and get the categories info for the current entry.

Regard's.

Comment: Took me a bit to configure, but it worked! I used GWCode plugin. Thank you.